# How to render Algolia's distinct grouping

Tags: algolia

I have a list of job openings. I'm using Algolia's [instantsearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/) library to render search results through these jobs.

Right now they render one-per-line:

- company.name, job.title
- company.name, job.title
- company.name, job.title

I'd like for them to render like Algolia describes here (they even use a job listing as an example)
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/distinct#how-distinct-works

- company.name

  - job.title
  - job.title
  - job.title

My question is: how do I render these distinct/grouped results using instantsearch.js?
I had hoped that once I enable 'distinct', Algolia would return it's hits in a grouped-by fashion, but it is still being returned as a flat-file list of jobs (just with a _distinctSeqID attribute)

Am I doing something wrong, or is it the actual intention that I take care of the grouping myself in my frontend. If so, is there a real purpose to the distinct method?

Ideally, I would have Algolia adding example code for the specific example they give there, being the job listing. But that is currently not the case.

Thanks!

Comment: i'm facing the same issue, it seems that this is their way of doing it for now.